# How to programatically create wifi connection os setting dialog

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-settings

I want to design an app which shows a list of wifi networks available and it shows the wifi connection setting dialog box when it is selected. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager. It allows you to send the intent in the specified time.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent("WhatEverYouWant");
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, startPIntent);
```

In manifest file add your receiver with appropriate action same as in the Intent. And from your receiver show the notification.

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.YourOnReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="WhatEverYouWant" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

More info on sending Intent using AlarmManager here
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))